# Is real line disconnected in discrete topology?

Tags: general-topology

My professor told me that the real line is connected in any topology. But i am thinking that if for example we consider the discrete topology in $\mathbf R$ i.e every subset is open then for any $x$ in $\mathbf R$ $(-\infty,x) \cup [x,\infty)$ would be a partition of open sets such that their union is $\mathbf R$ and thus $\mathbf R$ is disconnected in discrete topology. Is what i am saying wrong? why?

Comment: Any space with more than one point is disconnected in the discrete topology. You're right.

Comment: Cheers that makes sense. I guess my professor got confused...

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood your professor.  Or perhaps he misspoke.  In either case, ask him, not us.

Comment: @GEdgar I just want to clarify whether this is something I'd like to take to meta: what part of OP's question do you find unsuitable to this site?

Comment: As a comment, I gave the OP some advice.  Sometimes I do that even when the question is suitable for this site...

Answer (score 4):

You are correct. The only discrete spaces that are connected are those with at most one point, since otherwise, they have a non-empty proper subset that is both open and closed.